# Setting an alternate image for a div background with css

Tags: html, css

How would I set an alternate background image for this (text) through css?

```
<div id = 'id'></div>

 #id
{
   background-image: url(image);
}
```

**Edit:** By alternate I mean this:

Say that `image` is this:[image]

If for some reason this image cannot load I want the `div` to contain the text "Stop"

Comment: What do you mean by **alternate**? That CSS should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not exist. Please refer to the following link for an in-depth explanation.

http://www.inspiredbuddy.com/accessibility/no-alternative-text-for-css-background-images/

CSS is used not to load content, but for aesthetic purposes only. All images in the CSS should be asserted to exist on the server, before that server goes live!

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but I guess I have to take it